# Failing to get required output from list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list, iteration, string-formatting, list-comprehension

I am working on a program to determine if votes from an election are valid and count the votes to find a winner. Forewarning, I am quite new to python and coding in general.

Currently, I am reading votes from a comma separated text file - each line is a single ballot, and each vote within the ballot needs to be checked for validity, where a valid vote is any positive integer and there are the same amount of votes as there are candidates (There are 5 candidates). Votes will be normalised by another function.

There is another function which reads candidate names into a list - the vote index matches up with the candidate index when counting votes. The rubrick for determining validity has a few exceptions e.g, blank votes on a ballot are converted to zero for that candidate, and ballots with more than 5 votes are ignored entirely.

**Here is the portion of code reading the ballots.**

```
def getPapers(f, n):

x = f.readlines() #read f to x with \n chars
strippedPaper = [line.strip("\n") for line in x] #stores ballot without \n chars. 
print(strippedPaper)#print without \n chars
print()

strippedBallot = [item.replace(' ', '') for item in strippedPaper] #remove whitespace in ballots
print(strippedBallot) #print w/out white space
print()

#Deal with individual ballots
m = -1
for item in strippedBallot:
    m += 1
    singleBallot = [item.strip(',') for item in strippedBallot[m]]

    print(singleBallot)

getPapers(open("testfile.txt", 'r'), 5)
```

**Contents of testfile.txt**

```
1,2, 3, 4

,23,
9,-8
these people!
4,    ,4,4
5,5,,5,5
```

**This is the output**

```
#Output with whitespace.
['1,2, 3, 4 ', '', ', 23, ', '9,-8', 'these people!', '4,    ,4,4', '5,5,,5,5']

#Output with whitespace removed.
['1,2,3,4', '', ',23,', '9,-8', 'thesepeople!', '4,,4,4', '5,5,,5,5']

#Output broken into single ballots by singleBallot.
['1', '', '2', '', '3', '', '4']
[]
['', '2', '3', '']
['9', '', '-', '8']
['t', 'h', 'e', 's', 'e', 'p', 'e', 'o', 'p', 'l', 'e', '!']
['4', '', '', '4', '', '4']
['5', '', '5', '', '', '5', '', '5']
```

Each single vote will be passed to another function to check for validity and normalisation. The problem is the way each ballot has been formatted after output e.g ['1,2,3,4'] is converted to ['1', '', '2', '', '3', '', '4'] - **first question is how can i eliminate the commas from the list without creating blank spaces?** These spaces will be counted when checking the votes, and the ballot will be invalidated because it has more votes than candidates! (blank spaces are converted to a vote of zero).

**Second,**, ['', '2', '3', ''] needs to read as ['', '23', ''] or it will count 0, 2, 3, 0 instead of 0, 23, 0, and the final vote tally will be wrong, and ['9', '', '-', '8'] should read as ['9', '', '-8'] or '-', '8' will read as two votes instead of one invalid vote of -8.

Is there a better method than what I'm using for retrieving comma separated items, which won't create empty spaces and incorrectly break up list items?

Comment: Add the content of your testfile.txt to the question.

Comment: Sure. I've added it in between the input and output sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input file is as below:

```
-bash-4.1$ cat testfile.txt
1,2, 3, 4
, 23,
9,-8
these people!
4,    ,4,4
5,5,,5,5
```

Your program simplified a little:

```
def getPapers(f):
    x = f.readlines() #read f to x with \n chars
    strippedPaper = [line.strip("\n") for line in x] #stores ballot without \n chars. 
    print(strippedPaper)#print without \n chars
    print()

    strippedBallot = [item.split(",") for item in strippedPaper] #remove whitespace in ballots
    print(strippedBallot) #print w/out white space
    print()

    for item in strippedBallot:
        print(item)

getPapers(open("testfile.txt", 'r'))
```

Comment: This seems to help, the output is now in a format which will make checking for validity easier.

Comment: @CamAtkinson Please mark your question as answered if you found what you are looking for.